# Remember me in Login with Cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I tried remember me with cookies but I can not succeed.it throws null refernce exception.
How can I fix it?

in pageload method

```
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Cookies["mail"].Value) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Cookies["pass"].Value)) {

        TextBox1.Text = Request.Cookies["mail"].Value;

        TextBox2.Text = Request.Cookies["pass"].Value;}
    }
```

in CheckedChanged method

```
    if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
    {
        Response.Cookies["mail"].Value = TextBox1.Text;
        Response.Cookies["pass"].Value = TextBox2.Text;
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Cookies["mail"].Value) && 
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Cookies["pass"].Value))
```

By

```
if (Request.Cookies["mail"] != null && 
    Request.Cookies["pass"] != null &&
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Cookies["pass"].Value)
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Cookies["mail"].Value))
```

If `Request.Cookies["mail"]` or `Request.Cookies["pass"]` is null your `if` will throw the exception you describe.

Another suggestion: if you're using [`Forms Auhentication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wff0kyh) you can use built in classes to support your login and related features. Reinvent the wheel in relation to security in not a good strategy.

For instance, I see that you're storing the password in plain text on the cookie. **This is a very bad idea.**